# How to sort a cursor based on a time string

Tags: android, sorting, android-cursor

My question if fairly simple, I have this segment of code

```
Cursor mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
            PlayerContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI, fulldataColumns, null, null,
            Players.SCORE +" ASC");
```

This code, from everything I've seen, should be sorting the cursor in ascending order based on Players.SCORE but it is not.

For reference Players.SCORE will always be a string in the format
mm:ss:msmsms ( read minute:second:millisecond).

Also here is the code for the query method in my ContentProvider

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    checkColumns(projection);
    queryBuilder.setTables(PlayerContract.Players.PLAYERS_TABLE_NAME);
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType) {
    case ALL_SCORES:
    break;
    case SCORE_ID:
    queryBuilder.appendWhere(PlayerContract.Players.ID + "="
    + uri.getLastPathSegment());
    break;
    default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    // Notify potential listeners
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
```

My question is why dose this code not work and how can I fix it?

(Another interesting note about this code is that I am also trying to add a limit statement to the end of the sort, which I have read works, however mine is not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this question. As it turns out my code was correct, however for some reason that I am still working on my ContentProvider.query() was being called twice. Once with the correct parameters and again with incorrect parameters.(i.e: sortOrder == null).

Also note that you can not sort a string of numbers in numerical order as sql sorts ints and strings differently

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If I am reading [the SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) correctly, `date()` expects a value of the form `%Y-%m-%d`. Yours is not.</strike>

If you are using two-digit minute and second values, this should sort without any function.

(above was from original question, not the update)

Also, you are querying a `ContentProvider`. There is no requirement that a `ContentProvider` offer sorting. If this is your own `ContentProvider`, you need to check on its side whether or not it is passing the sort clause on to SQLite or whatever your backing store is.

Comment: Thank you I was thinking this was wrong but was trying as a recommendation from else where. Ill edit my question to show what I had originally

Comment: Ok I went and checked and added what I am pretty sure is the code in question. It seems to look like it will work but I may be wrong

Comment: @Noob: That looks OK. You might consider adding [a call to `buildQuery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#buildQuery(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and logging it, to see if that gives you any clues.

Comment: Creating a string using buildQuery and passing(projection,null,null,null,Players.SCORE+" ASC","2") Gave me the output SELECT _id,firstname, score, number FROM WHERE ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 2       Which looks fairly correct to me

Comment: @Noob: That doesn't look like valid SQL. You are missing a table and a `WHERE` clause to go with the `WHERE` term. The `ORDER BY` bit looks OK. Assuming that the problem with the logging lies with where/when you called `buildQuery()`, then the only remaining possibility I can think of is that the data isn't what you think it is (e.g., you are not using numbers with a consistent number of digits for the time segments). To sort, 4 minutes, 9 minutes, and 15 milliseconds would have to be stored like `"04:09:015"`, with leading zeros.