# Having issues limiting the return size of a cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have this code

```
Cursor mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
            PlayerContentProviderDB.CONTENT_URI, PLAYERS_PROJECTION, null, null,
             Players.SCORE +" ASC"
             + " LIMIT 2");
```

I am having trouble getting the limit to work. I have read this format works but it is not in this case. Currently I am aware that my sorting clause does not work as intended either and I do not know why (Please see
[How to sort a cursor based on a time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576141/how-to-sort-a-cursor-based-on-a-time-string)).

Is there a reason why neither statement is working? If so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the above code is fine. There error lies in the fact that my query method is being called twice for unknown reasons with sortOrder == null on the second call.